# how to create a new copy list by value

Tags: c#, deep-copy

i use a c# win application.
i would to make a copy of my list not for refereance but by value.
i would my first list remains always original and if i make a change in new list, this change doesn't appear in original list.
i have tried this code but doesn't wotk beacuse copy to reference and not to value

```
_TracList = GetMyData();
List<FileVers> wTemp = new List<FileVers>(_TracList);
```

i would modify wTemp and take _TracList with original value;
how can i make a copy by value of my List?

Answer (score 0):

Your code *does* create a value copy: If you remove an element from `wTemp`, it will still be available in `_TracList`.

However, your code *does not* make a value copy of each *element*, so if you *modify* an entry in `wTemp`, it will also be modified in `_TracList`. C# cannot make a deep copy, since it has no idea how to make a value copy of your custom `FileVers` class.

If you want a copy *of each element*, you will have to create it manually:

```
var wTemp = _TracList.Select(x => MakeCopyOf(x)).ToList();
```

`MakeCopyOf` is a method that you must supply, which takes a `FileVers` instance and returns a copy of it.